# RxAndroid: UI changes on Schedulers.io() thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I have simple job on IO thread which is changing home screen wallpaper, after that I'm trying to run some animation on UI thread:

```
     AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))
       .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .subscribe(v -> setWallpaperOnSeparateThread());

private void setWallpaperOnSeparateThread() {
     WallpaperHelper.setBitmapAsWallpaper(photoViewAttacher.getVisibleRectangleBitmap(), getBaseActivity());

     AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))
       .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(integer -> loadFinishAnimationAfterSetWallpaper());
}
```

but this approach results in error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observers must subscribe from the main UI thread, but was Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]`

I've tried to change second Observable to:

```
  AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))
    .delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(integer -> loadFinishAnimationAfterSetWallpaper());
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))` throw an exception as it's not called from the Main Thread

This code is not called in the main thread because you observe on `Schedulers.io` in this code (see bellow), than latter call `AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))`

```
AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))
   .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .subscribe(v -> setWallpaperOnSeparateThread());
```

You want to perform a task in io thread, then perform a task in main thread. To do so, you can chain you call using one `Observable`.

```
AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))
   .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .flatMap(v -> Observable.defer(() -> WallpaperHelper.setBitmapAsWallpaper(photoViewAttacher.getVisibleRectangleBitmap(), getBaseActivity())))
   .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(v -> loadFinishAnimationAfterSetWallpaper());
```

Please note I use `defer` to represente you async task as an `Observable` but you can replace the `flatMap` call with `doOnNext` call.

```
AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.just(0))
   .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .doOnNext(v -> WallpaperHelper.setBitmapAsWallpaper(photoViewAttacher.getVisibleRectangleBitmap(), getBaseActivity()))
   .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(v -> loadFinishAnimationAfterSetWallpaper());
```

Comment: doOnNext() with delay() solved my problem - upvoted for this

Answer (score 5):

Actually observeOn is for the subcscriber thread while subscribeOn is for observable thread. So you should reverse them

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Comment: same exception in this case.