# Chaining 2 different async operations that is dependant on the value of an observable

Tags: android, rx-java

Hi all I'm new to RxJava and trying to wrap my head around some concepts. I need to get a value from the api, and run 2 more queries to the api that is dependent on the value.

I tried implementing it this way but it's giving me a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Is there a way to 'fork' the stream, or is my understanding flawed? Any help is appreciated.

```
ConnectableObservable<Value> getSomeValueStream =
                _api
                    .someHttpAsyncTask()
                    .map(parseJsonResponse)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .publish();

getSomeValueStream 
            .flatMap(HttpAsyncTask2Stream)
            .subscribe();

getSomeValueStream 
            .flatMap(HttpAsyncTask3Stream)
            .subscribe();

getSomeValueStream.connect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you want an io-scheduler to do the network calls and not the main thread. So this:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Should be this:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.io())
```

Remember that `observeOn` causes an observable's emissions to be done on a different schedulers, which leads to the network calls to be executed on the main thread (hence the error).

If there is no io-scheduler in android use an appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! For people who have the same issues, if your UI changes are dependent on the async values one can call .observeOn again on the UI thread after the long running io op is done. [Further info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211397/rxandroid-ui-changes-on-schedulers-io-thread).